Translate array operations to a pure numpy method
How can I translate this code:
rose_number = np.copy(rosehrs)

for a in range(0,1597):
    for b in range(0,2145):
        for c in range(0,64):
            rose_number[a][b][c] = round((rosehrs[a][b][c]/totalhrs[a][b])*100,2)

Into a numpy function? Maybe using np.divide is an option with where but I'm not sure of the operations needed.

Please provide a [mre] of rosehrs and totalhrs, without it your question is not reproducible

Your inputs are not fully clear, but you most likely can vectorize your operation with:
out = np.round(rosehrs/totalhrs[..., None]*100, 2)

With a random example:
np.random.seed(0)
rosehrs = np.random.random((1597, 2145, 64))
totalhrs = np.random.random((1597, 2145))

this runs in about 1.4s:
1.41 s ± 65.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

The loop variant took about 18 minutes.
